# Is it possible to mount docker container on VS code?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-machine

I saw it but I can't remember where I saw it.

It looked like seeing inside Linux, mounting the docker container on VS Code on Mac OS.

Is it possible to mount the docker container on VS code?

Comment: Are you talking about opening a VSCode editor inside the Docker container or about Docker volumes and [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "mount", I presume you're talking about opening VSCode inside the container instead of Docker volumes and [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). You can install the [Remote Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) extension to do this.

Also see the docs mentioned by @AttilaViniczai for how to create development containers/dev contianers for VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/create-dev-container

1. Install the VSCode extension

[image: remote containers extension]

2. Select the Remote Explorer tab on the left side of VSCode and make sure you have **Containers** selected from the drop down menu.

[image: select containers]

3. Double click the container you want to work on and/or right click and select **Attach to Container**. This will attach VSCode to that Docker container and install its required tools inside automatically.

[image: attach to container]

For more information about this, you can see the VSCode documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) and a tutorial [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-tutorial).

Comment: Exactly. I also want to point out that the name of this concept is development container in VSCode terminology. A development container is a Docker container where the workspace gets volume mounted into. A dev container also runs a VSCode server that the VSCode application connects to.

Comment: There is another doc for VSCode that I found more concise and helpful than the other docs available: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/create-dev-container

Comment: Thanks! Agreed those are better docs, @AttilaViniczai I'll add.